# Handling ambiguous handler methods mapped in REST application with Spring

Tags: spring, rest, path-variables, request-mapping

I tried to use some code as below:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Brand getBrand(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    return brandService.getOne(id);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Brand> getBrand(@PathVariable String name) {
    return brandService.getSome(name);
}
```

But I got error like this, how can I do?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path 'http://localhost:8080/api/brand/1': {public java.util.List com.zangland.controller.BrandController.getBrand(java.lang.String), public com.zangland.entity.Brand com.zangland.controller.BrandController.getBrand(java.lang.Integer)}
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:375) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Spring can't distinguish if the request `GET http://localhost:8080/api/brand/1` will be handled by `getBrand(Integer)` or by `getBrand(String)` because your mapping is ambiguous.

Try using a query parameter for the `getBrand(String)` method. It seems more appropriate, since you are performing a query:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Brand getBrand(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    return brandService.getOne(id);
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Brand> getBrands(@RequestParam(value="name") String name) {
    return brandService.getSome(name);
}
```

Using the approach described above:

- Requests like `GET http://localhost:8080/api/brand/1` will be handled by `getBrand(Integer)`.
- Requests like `GET http://localhost:8080/api/brand?name=nike` will be handled by `getBrand(String)`.

---

**Just a hint:** As a common practice, prefer plural nouns for collections of resources. So instead of `/brand`, use `/brands`.

Comment: what if the controller also has a `getAll()` method with the following URL: `http://localhost:8080/api/brand`. How to have all three together (getAll and getBrand by name will have conflicting paths)

Comment: @fireball.1 The presence (or absence) of the `name` query parameter will determine whether the server will fetch all brands (or filter the brands by name).

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, i have described my problem in detail here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64913401/have-controller-methods-to-getall-getbyid-and-getbyemail-in-the-same-controller

Comment: @fireball.1 I've posted an answer for your question. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 13):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Brand getBrand(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    return brandService.getOne(id);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Brand> getBrand(@PathVariable String name) {
    return brandService.getSome(name);
}
```

When you run the app, and access the endpoints you tried coding up you realize the following, 'http://localhost:8086/brand/1' and 'http://localhost:8086/brand/FooBar' correspond to the same URL format (which can be described as protocol+endpoint+'brand'+). So SpringBoot is essentially confused if it should call the function 'getBrand' with a String datatype or an Integer. So to get over this I'd suggest you use a query parameter as mentioned by @cassiomolin or have separate paths for both invocations. This may be against the REST principles but assuming you are just doing a sample app this is another workaround.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/id/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Brand getBrand(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    return brandService.getOne(id);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/name/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Brand> getBrand(@PathVariable String name) {
    return brandService.getSome(name);
}
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Spring can handle this by specifying how to differentiate the variables, you can do this with a regex.

```
@GetMapping("/{id:\\d+}")
public Brand getBrand(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    return brandService.getById(id);
}

@GetMapping("/{name:.*\\D.*}")
public List<Brand> getBrand(@PathVariable String name) {
    return brandService.getByName(name);
}
```

In the example above the id is required to be only digits, while the name is required to contain at least one non-digit character.