# How to pass local date in path variable in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm writing  REST service.

I want to get all records by date that I pass in @Path variable.

**How Can I do that?**

What I tried to do:

Model Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
public class Test {
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String name;


    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate beginDate;


    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate endDate;


    private String activity;
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface TestRepository  extends JpaRepository<Test, Integer> {

    List<Test> findAllByName(String name);

    List<Test> findAllByBeginDate(LocalDate date);
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class TestService {

@Autowired
private final TestRepository testRepository;

public TestService(TestRepository testRepository) {
    this.testRepository = testRepository;
}

public List<Test> getAllTestsByBeginDate(LocalDate date) {
    return  testRepository.findAllByBeginDate(date);
   }
 }
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/")
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("test/all/{date}")
    public List<Test> getAllTestsByBeginDate(@PathVariable ("date") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") LocalDate date) {


    return testService.getAllTestsByBeginDate(date);
    }
  }
```

When I pass date like this, I get errors:

[image: Postman Get Method]

Comment: There is more than one mapping for the corresponding url to map. For instance in the method `getAllTestsByName` date mapping could be mapped to String mapping , giving error

Comment: You need to show us the whole `TestController` class, or at least its `getAllTestsByName` method.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/")
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("test/all/{date}")
    public List<Test> getAllTestsByBeginDate(@PathVariable @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") LocalDate date) {


    return testService.getAllTestsByBeginDate(date);
    }
  }
```

or this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35155916/handling-ambiguous-handler-methods-mapped-in-rest-application-with-spring) will help

Comment: Do you have another method defined in TestController?

Comment: I used Request Param instead of RequestMapping and it works! But it looks not so prettiy as RequestMapping in url Thank you!

Comment: btw, what is best practice to pass such things as name and date in url? throughRequest Mapping or RequestParam? I think Request Mapping looks more pretty

Comment: In case direct searchById kind of moments I would go for PathParam, while in case I have multiple parameter(in a limit and expose of data isn't an issue) like name, age, I would prefer RequestParam. Now If parameters exceeds like more than 3, then POST body is always option.

Comment: Just to add on for RequestMapping. Usually RequestMapping is used to map URL to java defined method.

Comment: Because it confused me at first, when you pass a parameter to `@PathVariable`, here's what it needs to look like: `@PathVariable (value = "date") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") LocalDate date`

Answer (score 1):

You can global configure any datetime format in **application properties**. Like:

```
spring.mvc.format.date=yyyy-MM-dd

spring.mvc.format.date-time=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

spring.mvc.format.time=HH:mm:ss
```