# Ambiguous handler error for Spring Boot Error controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ambiguous

I've been encountering this for a while now but I can't seem to find the reason why I'm getting this ambiguous error.

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
Sep 25 21:23:27 ip-172-31-29-87 web: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path 'http://172.31.29.87/error': {public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.sample.controller.WebsiteController.error404() throws java.lang.Exception, public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)}
```

This is my http configuration:

```
.and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/AccessDenied").
```

This is my /AccessDenied controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/AccessDenied")
public ModelAndView accessDenied() throws Exception {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("accessDenied");
    
    return model;
}
```

Really hope you could help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring couldn't find your end-point for handling error. I think you should specify Http method for `@RequestMapping`. Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55311282/13314717)  might be useful for use.

**Upd**
Also, I found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-access-denied-page) what you can just specify html page in `accessDeniedPage()` method. For example, you can create `error.html` or `error.jsp` and add this into your code `.and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/error.jsp")`. In this case you don't need anymore handle this request in your controller.

Comment: Thank you! .accessDeniedPage("/error.jsp") worked. :)